# Pointer inside pointer : How to know easily between two pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

This is my simple exercise:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
int *p = &a;
int **p2 = &p;
int *p3 = &b;
*p = **p2 + *p3;
*p3 = (**p2)--;
*p2 = p3;
**p2 = **p2 + 15;
```

The answer key said that the value of `a` is 14 and `b` is 30. How it can be? I'm very stuck at the pointer `**p2`, I need some explanation about this pointer.

Comment: Draw things, you'll better understand what's going on here.

Comment: What numbers do you get when you try it by hand? Remember that (x)-- evaluates to x's original value, and then decrements it afterwards.

Comment: I always stuck at this form, "*ptr and **ptr"

Comment: `*ptr` is a pointer while `**ptr` is a pointer to a pointer

Comment: Also, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and try to run `step` by step your program in a debugger (`gdb`), inspecting your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
int *p = &a;
int **p2 = &p;
int *p3 = &b;
```

`a` is 10, `b` is 5, `p` points at `a`, `p2` points at `p` and `p3` points at `b`.

```
*p = **p2 + *p3;
```

`a`'s value (`p` points at `a`) is set to `**p2` (what is pointed by `p`: `a`) plus `*p3` (which points at b): 15

```
*p3 = (**p2)--;
```

`b`'s value (`p3` points at `b`) is set to `**p2` (what is pointed by `p`: `a`): 15. And then `a` is decremented: 14.

At this point, `a` is 14 and `b` is 15.

```
*p2 = p3;
```

What `p2` is pointing (`p`) is set to `p3`. `*p2` will now point to what `p3` is pointing: `b`

```
**p2 = **p2 + 15;
```

`b`'s value is set to itself plus 15: 30

Comment: I think this is slightly wrong:  
"
`*p2 = p3;`  
p2 is set to point to p3. **p2 will now point to what p3 is pointing: b"  

What it does is to change p to be equal to p3, both will point at b. p2 doesn't change, it's still pointing on p. It makes the difference that the last line could also be written:  
`*p = *p + 15;`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
int *p = &a;
int **p2 = &p;
int *p3 = &b;
```

After these declarations and initializations, all of the following are true:

```
  p2 == &p
 *p2 ==  p  == &a
**p2 == *p  ==  a == 10
         p3 == &b
        *p3 ==  b ==  5
```

So we can substitute the pointer expressions for the things they point to:

```
*p = **p2 + *p3 ==> a = a + b // 10 + 5 == 15
*p3 = (**p2)--  ==> b = a--;  // b = 15, a = 14
```

Remember that `x--` evaluates to the current value of `x`, and as a *side effect* decrements it by 1.
So, in `b = a--`, `b` gets the value of `a` before the decrement.

After the expression

```
*p2 = p3 // equivalent to p = p3; p now points to the same thing as p3
```

our table now looks like

```
  p2 == &p
 *p2 ==  p ==  p3 == &b
**p2 == *p == *p3 ==  b == 15
```

Leaving us with

```
**p2 = **p2 + 15 ==> b = b + 15
```

So when we're done, `b` is 30 and `a` is 14.

Answer (score 0):

:)

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
int *p = &a;
int **p2 = &p;
int *p3 = &b;
*p = **p2 + *p3;
*p3 = (**p2)--;
*p2 = p3;
**p2 = **p2 + 15;
```

Starting from the above -

1- 10 is assign to a.

2- 5 is assign to b.

3- address of a is assign to pointer variable p.

4- address of pointer variable 'p' is assign to p2(which is a pointer to pointer variable).

5- address of b is assign to pointer variable p3.

6- A we know * is used to dereference the pointer. So here in **p2(you can understand it like this *(*p2) ) first * will dereference p2 which will give address of a and then the second * operator will deference it and give value of a. So *(*p2) is the value of a.
Now in the same expression in the *p3.p3 is holds the address of b so *p3 will give the value of b.
The result what you will get is 15.

7- In this expression first p2 will be deference then decremented by 1.As you know a is now 15 therefore it will become 14 after decrement. And *p3 will be 15(Read this :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy3d35h8.aspx).

8- Since **p2 is now 15 therefore 30 will be assigned into **p2.
Hope my explanation cleared your doubts.